# Tweepy bound method API.me

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy    
from tweepy import OAuthHandler    
import time    

consumer_key = '####'    
consumer_secret = '####'

key = '####'    
secret = '####'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)    
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)    
api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = api.me
```

Why won't this work? It errors out with:

> <bound method API.me of <tweepy.api.API object at 0x000001A9BC0ACB20>>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: I think from the error,  ```api.me``` is a method.  What you should be doing is ```user = api.me()```  Assuming there are no parameters for ```me()```.  That said,which version of tweepy are you using?

Comment: I did change it to api.me(), still no difference. results in the same error. latest version of tweepy, pip installed it earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with Python 3.9.4 and Tweepy 3.9.0:

```py
import tweepy
import json

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'

access_token = 'xxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = api.me()

print(json.dumps(user._json, indent=2))

# -> outputs the user object for the user with the associated access_token to console
# note that just using api.me (no parentheses) results in a bound method message
```

Comment: Still results in a bound method, :( I am using Python 3.9.4 as well, and Tweepy 3.9.0.

Comment: Switched to Python 3.8.5, same issue persists.

Comment: Are you sure you’re running this with Python 3? I ran `python3` to ensure I opened a Python 3 REPL (it reported the version at the start) and then I typed the commands one by one. If you are running this as a script, does it make a difference to run using `python3 script.py` instead of `python script.py`?

Comment: I am running it as a script. Upon typing python3 script.py, it says "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases." BUT if i run python --version it responds with "Python 3.8.5". Doing "py -3 script.py" results in the same bound error.

Comment: Switched to my Linux VM that has python 3.8.5, issue still persists. I used python3 script.py as well.